# What does Theta(1) operations mean?

Tags: algorithm

I was given this task:

```
Algorithm M(n)
if n=1 then
Execute Task A; // Requires Theta(1) operations
else

Execute Task B; //Requires 2n operations
end if
```

What does "Requires Theta(1) operations" mean?

Comment: It is a constant! means require constant time and will ignore in time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "Requires Theta(1) operations" mean?

It means, that *something* requires constant amount of operations in the average-case scenario.

---

**What is Big Theta?**
Big Theta notation (`Θ`) is an *Asymptotic Notation*, which denotes the *Average Case Complexity* of an algorithm.

Popular Asymptotic Notation letters are:

1. `Ο` (Big-O) – used to express *worst case complexity* scenario.
2. `Ω` (Big Omega) – used to express *best case complexity* scenario.
3. `θ` (Big Theta) – used to express *average case complexity* scenario.

Few examples:

- Ω(1) - means, that best-case scenario runs in *constant time* (we use `1` to denote constant running-time, that does not grow as the input grows);
- θ(n) - means, that average-case scenario runs in *n* time (running-time is said to be growing *linearly* to the growth of the input size);
- O(n<sup>2</sup>) - means, that worst-case scenario runs in *n*<sup>2</sup> time (running-time is said to be growing *quadratically* to the growth of the input size).

Additionally, have a look at [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation).

Comment: And how do you explain about "2n operations" here in term of time complexity? Thank you.

Comment: *n* is the size of your input. If your algorithm receives an input of array of size 10, and it iterates over that array two times, it takes 2n=2×10 operations to get done (if you don't have anything taking extra time in your loop's body). However, note, that `2` is a constant factor, which we disregard when we do asymptotic analysis. So 2n, 5n, or even 15n is just *n* when analysing the runtime complexity.

Comment: so in this case can i take C(1)=1?

Comment: In *which* case? You shall see an algorithm to analyse what it does and for how long, otherwise, it's not really possible to deduce the running time. However, I think, that in *most* cases - yes, you are right. If the input is of size 1, then the execution time will be constant, but we don't write input sizes as a constant integers.. now you can read a bit yourself from this, as, I think, you understood the main concept.